# Determine whether the set is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let {$f_n$} be a sequence of measurable functions. Determine whether the set {$\omega : \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }f_n(\omega)$ abs.converges} is measurable.

I think this set is measurable but have trouble proving this.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }f_n(\omega)$ abs.converges if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }|f_n(\omega)|$ converges. Then, we can use the definition of the convergence of a series to write this whole thing. Idea is to express the whole thing as a countable union/intersection of m'ble sets but the problem is a term of the form, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }|f_n(\omega)|<1/k$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can we extract $|f_n(\omega)$| out of this?. Is it fair enough to write $|f_n(\omega)|<1/k$ for all $n$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s_{n}(\omega)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f_{k}(\omega)|$, $s_{n}$ is a measurable function, so is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_{n}(\omega):=s(\omega)$, now the set is just $s^{-1}([0,\infty))$, which is a measurable set.

Comment: Oh, we use,

1) The sum of m'ble functions is m'ble.
2) Pointwise limit of a sequence of m'ble functions is m'ble.

By the way, can this be done using the definition of convergence of series. For any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $N$ s.t for all $n \geq N$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|f_n(\omega)|<1/k$. So, can we argue that the series abs.converges if for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $N$ s.t for all $n \geq N$, $|f_n(\omega)|<1/k$?

Comment: The problem is that, for those $\omega$ such that $\displaystyle\sum|f_{n}(\omega)|<1/k$ entails that $|f_{n}(\omega)|<1/k$ but not vice versa, so these two sets are not equal.

Comment: Indeed, the extended real valued function $s(\omega) = \sum_k |f_k(\omega)|$ is measureable.

Comment: @user284331

to clarify, isn't the set from the task $s^{-1}([0,\infty)) - s^{-1}(\infty)$, not $s^{-1}([0,\infty))$?

Comment: $s^{-1}[0,\infty)-s^{-1}(\infty)=s^{-1}([0,\infty)-\{\infty\})=s^{-1}[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @user284331, ty, I guess I misinterpret notation. Just one more dumb question if you could confirm: if $\omega \in s^{-1}([0, \infty))$ then $s(\omega)$ is finite and can't be $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, that is the right interpretation.